# Single PHP function with multiple fields and regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, function

I need to create a single function that intakes my regular expression and form field to validate multiple fields. Here's what I have:

```
if (preg_match ($fname_regex, $fname)) {
            $valid_fname = 1;
        } else {
            echo $fname_error_message;
        }

        if (preg_match ($lname_regex, $lname)) {
            $valid_lname = 1;
        } else {
            echo $lname_error_message;
        }

        if (preg_match ($phone_regex, $phone)) {
            $valid_phone = 1;
        } else {
            echo $phone_error_message;
        }

        if (preg_match ($city_regex, $city)) {
            $valid_city = 1;
        } else {
            echo $city_error_message;
        }

        if (preg_match ($state_regex, $state)) {
            $valid_state = 1;
        } else {
            echo $state_error_message;
        }

        //if all are fields are valid, go forward.
        if ($valid_fname && $valid_lname && $valid_phone && $valid_city && $valid_state) {
            $output_form = 0;
        } else {
            echo "<p>One of your fields is invalid. Please check and re-submit.</p>";
        }
```

But I need to have a single function that does this and only returns true or false. I don't know how to go about creating a function that would take multiple fields and multiple regex's. Any help?

Comment: Firstname and lastname regex? How? Please enlighten me.

Comment: I just check the field to be certain there are a specific amount of characters, in this case 2-15 alphabetic characters.

Comment: So what's the problem with function? Pass all arguments, or pass arrays as arguments.

Comment: And what do you need the regex for then? If the field only allows 2-15 characters then what is the regex supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass an array of informations about what to validate. The function could also store about what fails.

Here is an example :

```
function validate_form($infos, &$errors = []) {
    $errors = [] ;
    foreach ($infos as $name => $info) {
        if (!preg_match ($info['regexp'], $info['value'])) {
            $errors[$name] = $info['error'] ;
        }
    }
    return empty($errors) ; // returns true/false
}

$infos = [
    'fname' => ['regexp' => $fname_regex, 'value' => $fname, 'error' => $fname_error_message],
    'lname' => ['regexp' => $lname_regex, 'value' => $lname, 'error' => $lname_error_message],
    'phone' => ['regexp' => $phone_regex, 'value' => $phone, 'error' => $phone_error_message],
    'city'  => ['regexp' => $city_regex,  'value' => $city,  'error' => $city_error_message],
    'state' => ['regexp' => $state_regex, 'value' => $state, 'error' => $state_error_message],
];
$errors = [] ;
if (!validate_form($infos, $errors)) {
    echo "<p>One of your fields is invalid. Please check and re-submit.</p>";
    print_r($errors) ;
}
else {
   echo "<p>OK, form validated!</p>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @newDevNow99 You're welcome :) This code is not tested, but I hope it helps.